# Wish to connect 2021 Laptop to 2007 monitor. HDMI to DVI-D. Have a HDMI to VGA cable and a VGA to DVI adapter. Will this work?

Tags: hdmi, vga, dvi

I wish to connect the HDMI out of my 2021 laptop to my 2007 monitor which has DVI-D input. I aim to purchase an HDMI to DVI-D (if one with this configuration exists) cable. I currently have a HDMI to VGA cable and a VGA to DVI adapter. Will using this set up that I already own give me the same result as a HDMI to DVI-D cable?

Comment: Yes, the cable you need exists and costs pennies. It's just a cable, no conversion required. Don't use the converters you already have, just don't.

Answer (score 1):

You could use HDMI => VGA => VGA => DVI.

But it won't give you the same results, especially if you've a Monitor with integrated speaker(s) - but not only.

This is a more generic answer than the current question; and of course audio probably don't matter in this specific case. Thank you @ChanganAuto!

I'd acquire either an HDMI => DVI cable, or [this kind of HDMI to DVI adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07MJDYH21).

It's always fine to have this kind of adapter in your toolbox, in case of ;-)

Comment: Not quite. The main issue is a double conversion that can introduce all sorts of problems (and any of those converters is problematic on its own). Lossy/lossless isn't applicable here. The reason why a simple adpater or cable, not a converter, can be used for HDMI <> DVI(-D) is because they're compatible, i.e., HDMI was designed based on early standards. DP is also digital but not the same as the others. And audio isn't supported by the DVI standard so that part is wrong too (it probably won't matter for the OP).

Comment: Edited, you're right about the audio. I still think - but didn't test it though - if he's no choice and no budget, he could try the hdmi => vga => dvi solution. @ChanganAuto

Comment: Yes, and try they should while witing for the proper part.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I'm not running after reputation; if you wish to post this kind of reply I'll remove mine, no problem, you're welcome!

Comment: I'm not either. :) so +1.

Comment: Happy to see good people here, thank you - wishing you the best.